# Git is showing all changes from everybody in a branch as if my own changes

Tags: git, version-control

I'm not a master of git so excuse me if I'm onto something terribly wrong.

I'm on a team project and I've created a new branch Z from branch X (which was our development branch), made my changes to it and it has been on my local branch for about a week. At the same time, our team has decided to switch to a methodology and use new branch Y as the development branch. Since then, every commit by other people (and me, in other tasks) have been committed to branch Y. Today I wanted to merge my changes in branch Z to the new development branch Y. I've changed a total of about 15 files in total. However, when I try to merge the branch, git (we are on Visual Studio Online, if it makes any difference) I got a merge conflict on about 13 files (including some files I haven't even touched my entire life). I said "Abort" in Visual Studio. Went to branch Y, synced with it (which fetches, pulls, and pushes in order if required), went back to my branch Z, merged changes and tried to sync again. It said that I'm up to date. I've opened a pull request to merge Z onto Y and here is the trouble:

Git thinks that all commits/changes done by everybody in the team in the last week as my changes. The pull request includes literally hundreds of changes done by other people *which are already on the branch Y*. How can I make my Pull Request include only my changes in the branch, and why is Git even trying to merge changes onto Y that are already on branch Y, showing them as if they are all my changes (when it isn't) anyway?

Comment: Do you have separate commits of the changes you want to merge in Y?

Comment: Something about the way that you merged Y into Z introduced new diffs/patches into the commit history. Best bet is to either (1) rebase pre-merged Z onto Y and then open a new PR there or (2) make a new topic branch and cherry-pick all the relevant patches into it.

Comment: @Deep unfortunately yes.

Comment: Not really related, but may be helpful in future: Git doesn't really care *who wrote* a commit, it cares about commit *hash IDs* (`f378ace` and the like), and in some cases "patch IDs" (for `git cherry` and related operations). Meanwhile commits carry two dedicated strings for "author" and "committer" to let *you* (but not Git) care about who actually *wrote* a commit. The author is the person who wrote it and the committer is the person who stored it into the repository: these become different when you copy someone else's changes, as you might with `git rebase` for instance.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, hi, have you get the answer what you want? If yes, please mark it. It will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT the answer(s) address my personal issue as a workaround, they don't address the cause of the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess while merging `X` into `Z` and then trying to merge it into `Y` got something wrong or broken in your git history [Pockets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577414/pockets) mentioned. I don't have the exact answer of why this is happening but what I follow in this case is creating a new branch from the base branch and `cherry-pick` the commits:

```
git checkout Y
git fetch origin && git pull origin Y
git checkout -b new_X
git cherry-pick commit_hash
```

If you have multiple commits then `cherry-pick` the commits in sequential manner like cherry-picking the commit you committed first and so on.

You also have an option to `rebase` the branch but sometimes rebasing causes a lot of conflicts if done wrong or in these kind of cases. This is just my personal experience of conflicts while rebasing I am not saying it will come always so I prefer `cherry-pick` rather than `rebase` in this case.

Comment: I'll go with cherry-picking (even though it's not a single commit, it's just a few that I can pick). But I'd love to understand the true reason behind this problem in order to avoid it in the long run though.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important thing you must be sure that is **whether a branch named Z exist in remote** (maybe pushed by you or created by other).

If branch Z exist in remote repository, it has heavy odds that others modified branch Z. So it not only contains your changes after you pull from remote. So you must find those commit histories which are committed by you. There are two ways you can replay the your changes of branch Z to branch Y as below (we can use the graph to illustrate):

```
              I---J    Y
             /       
A---B---C---H          X (development)
     \
      D---E---F---G    Z
```

1. Find out the changes made by you.  Assume on branch Z, the commit D to F is made by you, so you can use `git checkout Z` and `git reset --hard HEAD~`, so HEAD will point to F on branch Z.

You can replay the changes to branch Y directly, use `git rebase --onto Y <commit id for B> Z`, the result will as:

```
              I---J---D’---E’---F’    Y
             /       
A---B---C---H                         X (development)
```

2. In order to not disturb others’ changes, you can also create new branch and copy your changes on it. Use these command:

`git checkout Z`

`git checkout <commit id for F>`

`git checkout -b newZ`

and then you can `create a pull request to merge branch newZ into branch Y`, this merge is for your changes.

**If Z branch is surely only exists in your local repo**, so these file is actually modified by other developers in Y branch. Such as the file test.cs didn’t not modified in Z branch, but other developers modified it in Y branch. When you merge Z into Y, the test.cs file will show conflict.

Comment: nope, Z doesn't exist remotely. I've created a unique name for it derived from a task that I'm working on, I'm 100% sure (and confirm) that there's no branch with the same name.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu. As you are so sure, so there is no hidden trouble for you to continue the merge. The reason why you found some files you weren’t modified, but appear in the merge conflict, is caused by **other developers modified these files in Y branches**. I added this situation in my answer, if it's really helps, please mark it as answer.

Comment: I'm sure no one has modified 400 files. There were "changed" files that haven't been touched by ANYONE for MONTHS.

Comment: Exclusive method, first please check your Z branch history, the history shows author and date. If all the changes were made by you, so the changed files which you never touched were surely modified by other develops. **Way to view Z branch history**: VS -> team explorer -> branches -> right click Z branch -> view history

Comment: Look, I know how to use git (even though, as I've stated, I'm not a master of it) and how to view history. Those files aren't really touched by anyone, that's why this is weird and I can't understand why it's happening at the first place.